# Extract elements from specified column for each row in vector

Tags: r

I have a vector say

```
column_index<-c(2,1,3)
```

and a data frame say

```
data<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(1,6,9),C=c(1,2,3))
```

Now I want a vector such that first element is element in data corresponding to row 1 and column index given by first element in column_index. The second element will be row 2 and column index given by second element in column_index and so on. The vector will have 3 elements. Is there any way to acheive this without looping?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18056799/946850

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the column index, `cbind` with the row index  (`1:nrow(data)`) to extract the elements.

```
data[cbind(1:nrow(data), column_index)]
```